# Display table (ag grid) after all datas are fetched

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I've got a table which I want to display only when `this.rowData` is entirely filled up (and thus all datas are fetched). Problem is I fill it up with two http calls like so :

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasks(this.item.availableTasks$); // This are the first data I want to fetch
    this.getTasks(this.item.myTasks$); // This are the second data I want to fetch (now this.rowData have all the datas I need)

  }

  getTasks(taskType): void {
    // taskType is a replaySubject that returns an Observable
    taskType.subscribe( 
      (tasksObservable: Observable<any>) => {
        tasksObservable.subscribe(
          (tasks: any) => {
            for (const task of tasks) {
              this.rowData.push(task ); // This is where i push datas into my array
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Here, I call `getTasks` two times in order to fill up my `rowData` array. When console loggin rowData in ngOnInit it displays correctly all my datas. But the result I'm seeing is only the datas from my first call.

Here is the table :

```html
<ag-grid-angular
    *ngIf="rowData.length != 0"
    class="col-12"
    style="height: 500px;" 
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [enableColResize]="true"
    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="15"
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

How can I wait for the two calls to end before displaying the table?
Bonus question: my `getTasks` method is a bit messy because of the double subscribe, how can I clean it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware of immutability in Angular 2+, see https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/immutable/what_is_immutability.html.

You should push new items to `this.rowData` with:

```
this.rowData = [
  ...this.rowData,
  task
];
```

The `this.rowData.push()` method is not respecting the immutability pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Any idea how should I solve my issue though? :)